# use tcl script to open a txt file (to make a txt file pop out on the screen)

Tags: file, tcl

How to really "open" the txt file (already know the file path), I mean, to pop out on the screen, by writing a tcl script? Thank you!

Comment: By **open**, did you mean open it using an application? What platform are you on (Win, Mac, Linux, ...) and what application do you want to use?

Answer (score 2):

Invoking the system “preferred” text editor is relatively easy, but not very portable. Assuming that `$theFilename` contains the name of the file as Tcl understands it, and that it is not a file on one of Tcl's virtual filesystems:

### Mac

```
exec open [file normalize $theFilename]
```

### Unix/Linux

```
exec xdg-open [file normalize $theFilename]
```

Or, if you're in a terminal and like the classic method:

```
exec $::env(EDITOR) [file normalize $theFilename] <@stdin >@stdout 2>@stderr
```

(You probably ought to also check for the `VISUAL` environment variable before the `EDITOR` environment variable. Or just fire it into the GUI with `xdg-open`…)

### Windows

```
exec {*}[auto_execok start] "" [file nativename [file normalize $theFilename]]
```

Yes, that empty argument is necessary (especially when a directory or file has a space in it); `start` has *horrible* syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by *open*, you meant *open using an application/program*. On Windows:

```
exec notepad.exe /path/to/file.txt
```

On Mac:

```
exec open /path/to/file.txt             ;# Open using default application
```

or:

```
exec open -a TextEdit /path/to/file.txt ;# Open using a specific application
```

Comment: For the windows case 'exec {*}[auto_execok start] $filename' is a better bet as start will launch the defined associated program which may not be notepad. On Unix - xdg-open commonly achieves the same effect.

Comment: Nice! I am going to try them out. Thank you for the tip.